# Remove duplicated lines from file working, but not displaying correct index

Tags: delphi, duplicates, delphi-10.3-rio, tstringlist

The following code works fine removing correct duplicated lines, but when i show **`I`**  before remove the line of *StringList* is displayed correctly the index (**`I`**) only of the first ocurrence of duplicated, after, the index is showed wrong not corresponding to correct (always minor than real index). How fix it?

This is the code:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.Classes,
  System.SysUtils;

var
  slSrc, slDup: TStringList;
  I, J: Integer;

begin
  try
    slDup := TStringList.Create;
    try
      slSrc := TStringList.Create;
      try
        slSrc.LoadFromFile('C:\src.txt');

        for I := 0 to Pred(slSrc.Count) do
        begin
          for J := Pred(slSrc.Count) downto I + 1 do
          begin
            if SameStr(slSrc[I], slSrc[J]) then
            begin
              // Ex; If 1º dup index is = 3, is showed 3. OK
              // If 2º dup index is = 15, is showed always a minor like 13 for example
              // and continue displaying wrong index for next dups

              Writeln(IntToStr(I) + ' : ' + slSrc[I]);
              slDup.Add(slSrc[I]);
              slSrc.Delete(I);
            end;
          end;
        end;
        slSrc.SaveToFile('C:\src.txt');
        slDup.SaveToFile('C:\dup.txt');
      finally
        slSrc.Free;
      end;
    finally
      slDup.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If removing duplicates with higher indices don't violate your rules, just make outer loop downward. In this case removing preserves the rest.

```
 for I := Pred(slSrc.Count) downto 0 do
    begin
      for J := 0 to I - 1 do
 ...
         slSrc.Delete(I);
```

Comment: Thank you, very nice!